# How to pivot one colum with n categories into n binary values column?

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot-table, data-transform

I have a following dataframe:

| id | gender | name | ... | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | John | ... | Withdrawn |
| 2 | F | Mary | ... | Pass |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 10 | F | Kate | ... | Fail |

And I want to transform it into a dataframe like this:

| id | gender | name | ... | Withdrawn | Pass | Fail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | John | ... | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | F | Mary | ... | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 10 | F | Kate | ... | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Is something like this possible with using functions like `pivot_table` or is it necessary to write a function and then loop through every row and append a value to corresponding column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as using dummy variables:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['status'])
df = df.drop(columns = ['status'])
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't heard of the get_dummies function before, it seems very useful.

Comment: Yes, it is used commonly to get advantage of categorical variables. It changes categorical variables to variables of 0 or 1, which makes it easy for Machine learning tasks to predict based on those categorical values. @Jamess11

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and `join` on the original dataframe in which you dropped the 'status' column:

```
df.drop(columns='status').join(pd.get_dummies(df['status']))
```

output:

```
   id  gender  name    Fail  Pass  Withdrawn
0    1      M   John      0     0          1
1    2      F   Mary      0     1          0
2   10      F   Kate      1     0          0
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! Haven't heard of the get_dummies function before, seems very useful.